# How to solve an arg max question?

Tags: calculus

I have no idea how to solve an $\arg \max$ mathematically, for example $\arg \max(x(10-x))$.
I know the solution is $x=5$, but how do I get there (for more difficult exercises I will have to solve). Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a quadratic then you could complete the square.
$$x(10-x) \equiv 10x-x^2 \equiv -(x^2-10x) \equiv -((x-5)^2-25) \equiv -(x-5)^2+25$$
This tells us that the maximum is $x=5$ and $y=25$.

If you have something of higher degree, you could differentiate to find the turning points.
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!y}{\operatorname{d}\!x} = 10-2x$$
We see that $10-2x=0$ if and only if $x=5$. When $x=5$, $y=25$. This is a maximum since when $x=0$, $y=0$ and when $x=10$, $y=0$.

Comment: so, f(x)=(10x-x^2), f'(x)=10-2x=0. great, thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But you *must* check it's a maximum. If $f'(x)=0$ then it *could* be a minimum (or even an inflexion). The formal test for a maximum is $f'(x)=0$ **and** $f''(x)<0$. P.S. Don't forget to vote for helpful answers.

Comment: thanks fly by night for the answer. helped me out a lot